# Meteor.publish is not a function

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-publications

I have a **publications.js** file that ONLY includes

```
Meteor.publish('org', function(_id){
    return Organizations.findOne(_id);
});
```

When things render I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.publish is not a function
```

What am I missing here... I'm sure it's painfully obvious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably accidentally running the code on the client. You have two choices:

1. Place the publish code in a file under the `/server` directory in your app.
2. Wrap the above inside of an `if (Meteor.isServer) {}` block.

(1) Has the advantage of not transmitting the publish code to the client.

Suggested reading: [Structuring your application](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: That does fix the issue... although I don't understand why my structure doesn't solve the problem as my understanding was anything in the server folder would only execute on the server.

Comment: `server` needs to be lower cased. `Server` will share to both the client and the server.

Comment: Ha, you're kidding me. Ah man... So when I change my app structure to be the proper case... it breaks. Why would that be?

Comment: My router routes were in the *server* folder. Sheesh. I'm good now. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is at the root, you need to wrap it with:

`if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  /* ... */
}`

The `Meteor.publish` method only exists on the server.